# popup calendars

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I change the format of a popup calendar in asp.net.Currently is shows me: MM-dd-yyyy but I want dd-MM-yyyy. I heard about some changes in the webconfig file but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Internationalisation (I18n) and Localisation (L10n) are tricky. Especially since it can depend on the system settings of the machine hosting the website. Which control are you looking at in particular? They will handle formats different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `Format` accordingly:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="dd-MM-yyyy"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb79761a-ca08-44ee-b142-b06b3e2fc22b.aspx)
- [Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)